# c# merge 2 solution and publish program

Tags: c#, project, publish

I have 2 different solution like A project and B project in Visual Studio with C# Windows Form.

I have merged (B) project in my existing project (A) by right-clicking on the project name and selecting Add->Existing project option.

And after that I added references B project to A project.

In this way, I was able to access and run forms in two different projects. So far, no problem.

The question is that; how can i publish the 2 project together in one project. When i try the publish, just A project was published and there is no B project.

Comment: If your dependencies are project-project exe, the second executable should be available in the deploy result. But I think it is better to convert one of the two projects into a class library (dll)